# The correct way to say something is hired on an hourly basis

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number, articles, time

Which of the following is correct?

> We hire our bicycle...
>
> 1. by the hour.
> 2. by hours.
> 3. by an hour.
> 4. for hours.

Comment: In America it is customary to say, "We rent our bicycles by the hour."  Hire is not typically used to talk about renting- it is used in conjunction with jobs. Thus I can hire an employee. I can hire a band to play music. I can hire a landscaping company to redo my front yard etc.  But I would rent a bicycle.  For things like taxis we neither rent nor hire them, we just call them.  I understand this may be different in other English-speaking countries.

Comment: @Jim Hiring is a perfectly fine alternative to renting. You can hire a car; you can also hire a TV. You can buy things on *hire purchase*.

Comment: To the OP, this question is likely to be closed as you didn't specify what sort of problem you are having with this. It feels to me that you simply want others to do the work for you. Tell us how you interpret each choice and what you think is correct, then this question might have some merit.

Comment: @JamesJiao: Jim is right, in the U.S., using the word _hire_ in that way would get you a lot of puzzled looks. Interesting how Macmillan's [American dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/hire#hire_4) lists this as a secondary meaning, with a _BRITISH_ tag, while their [British dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hire#hire_4) lists it as a primary meaning.

Comment: @J.R. I am aware of that. I should've gone on to add that it's a fine alternative *where I live*.

Comment: @JamesJiao: I'm glad you made your comment. I hadn't heard that use of the word before; that's now been added to my list of the many new things I've learned on EL&U.  P.S. I'm renting a car next month - perhaps I'll drop that word at the hiring counter, just for fun.

Comment: @JamesJiao Actually, no; that’s only in the Common Tongue / CommonSpeak / speech in the Commonwealth. In American English,  it works differently: one can only **rent *things/objects***, never hire them, whereas one can only **hire *people***, not rent them. Americans really cannot/do not/will not ever use *hire* for things nor *rent* for people. Well, unless you’re talking about thingifying a prostitute by using *rent* on a human: *rentboy* is not a nice word. You can’t hire a horse, either; **hiring requires a *sentient agent*** to accept being hired in America.

Comment: @tchrist Again, how are my points contradicting with yours? Which part of "I should've gone on to add that it's a fine alternative where I live." did you not understand?

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether OP is hiring ("renting" in the US, apparently) bicycles as a *supplier* or as a *customer*, if the standard charging unit is an hour, said bicycles are hired/rented **by the hour**.

Comment: Maybe Americans can’t hire things because one can’t pay the things. Only sentient agents get to be hired.  If you rent things, you’re not paying the thing, but the owner of the thing. It might also be that hiring requires a sentient agent to accept the job. You couldn’t hire an umbrella because you can’t get the umbrella to make the choice of being hired, and it can’t get paid. Instead, you rent the umbrella from its owner, who’s the one who accepts the rental and who gets paid for its use.

Comment: @tchrist- well said.

Comment: @tchrist: Perhaps so, but doesn't that all come down to the definition of [rent](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hire#hire_9)? Clearly, in much of the English-speaking world, you absolute _can_ hire something, even if you are paying the owner, and not the object itself.

Comment: @tchrist: I understand the distinction. But it's not one which would normally be made in the UK, where we would ["hire a cement mixer"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hire+a+cement+mixer%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). For us, *renting* tends to apply to longer periods and/or living accomodation, but much of the time the words are interchangeable.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: As I use the terms, the bicycle owner rents out his cycles by the hour; as one of his customers I hire one for two hours.

Comment: @TimLymington: It seems at least some Americans only *hire* "sentient agents" - so I guess Microsoft could hire me for a job. I don't know if they'd allow me to "hire my staff to Microsoft", but that sounds a bit odd to me. Renting *people* (as either supplier or customer) sounds even more odd. Your distinction (supplier rents, customer hires) is again comprehensible to me, but I don't think it would affect my personal choice of verb, which is more based on duration (loosely - hire by the hour, rent by the month).

Comment: ...check out US/UK corpora for [hire him a / rent him a](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hire+him+a%2Crent+him+a&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which suggests the UK uses both about equally often, but the US significantly favours **rent** (I'm guessing in most cases, what follows "**a**" is an inanimate noun).